# How to debug Xamarin.Forms XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm finding Xamarin.Forms XAML very frustrating.

If I use this syntax...

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter1 x:Key="MyConverter1"/>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

I will get a System.NullReferenceException from InitializeComponent().  Nothing in the stack trace or output window or anywhere else tells me what is wrong.
Note: this syntax works fine in WPF.

After a lot of struggle I discovered I need this syntax...

```
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MyConverter1 x:Key="MyConverter1"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

Likewise for ListView DataTemplate.  This throws null reference exception...

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter1}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Because the proper syntax is this...

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter1}}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Again this syntax works fine in WPF.  I fully realize that Xamarin.Forms is not WPF but I getting weary of being sucker punched by null reference exceptions whenever I use a XAML construct that is valid in WPF.

What is the best way to debug Xamarin.Forms XAML issues?

Right now I am simply commenting stuff out until it starts working.  This is akin to putting print statements in imperative code.  Declarative code is supposed to be superior to imperative code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When there is a free and great book on this topic, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/ I wonder why you insist learning this technology by making simple mistakes. No easy way to debug, but if you do follow the tips, most of the issues won't happen at first.

Comment: enabling XAML compilation will catch some of these issues at build time: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: Can you describe more what you mean by `This throws null reference exception...`

Comment: And you can put a break point in your converter, but I need to know what you mean by what you said (see comment above)

Comment: Also make sure you have this: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:{ProperNameSpace};assembly={ProperAssembly}"`. But again, can't speak really to much more until I understand what you mean by null reference

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet it throws on startup in InitializeComponent().  So no breakpoint anywhere will work.  Yes, I have xmlns:local namespace...it would not compile without that.  Yes, the XAML is compiled.  I can look at the generated C# code...it does not help.

Comment: Check this link may be answer for you-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489404.aspx

Comment: @LexLi I did in fact read the book (Well, not cover to cover...it is 1161 pages).  Petzold does a great job of thoroughly examining a programming platform.  However it did not save me from these errors.  In fact the ResourceDictionary issue I've run into twice now.  There should be reasonable error messages.  Baring that I should be able to look at Xamarin Forms source code in the debugger. Cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Jason I am compiling the XAML.  This is the default apparently with the latest Xamarin Forms.  The 2 issues I've documented (and there are many, many others) are not caught.

Comment: @PratiusDubey No.  That reference is for Windows Workflows, which is a different implementation of XAML.  XAML is used in a lot of different technologies.

Comment: @AQuirky Yes, In XAMARIN  Form  there is no any tools to a debug directly from visual studio as  c#. Other way you can see the compilation issues/Error in Output windows. And i will recommend to use ReSharper. For details please check this link-https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22668/xaml-how-to-debug

Comment: Ok sounds like you don't have this line in your XAML. `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:{ProperNameSpace};assembly={Prope‌​rAssembly}"` Can you verify you have this?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Yes I have that.  Would not compile without it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there isn't really a good way of debugging XAML. Turning on Xaml compilation will help. It compiles all your forms code into IL which makes it faster and finds these sorts of problems at compile time. You may also want to look into the new c# markup extensions. They are still in beta, but they let you write your declarative ui in straight c# with full intellisense.

Also, you may wish to switch from using ListView to using the newer CollectionView. It's much more performant and is basically an in-place upgrade. More info [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-collectionview2/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This has tripped me up a few times too and I've been using Xamarin.Forms for 3 years now.

I mentioned that this was an issue on Twitter and was asked to raise it as an issue on Github.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1486

I added 2 examples which match with yours. If you can think of any more let me know and I'll add them.

Let's hope this gets fixed sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

I normally have 2 steps

1. add a try catch in code behind

```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    
    namespace TestApp.Views
    {
        public partial class AssetsPage : ContentPage
        {
            public WelcomePage()
            {
                try
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Remove code and keep on checking if the problem disappears

not really a magic solution but it helps the most especially when you have large groups of complicated code